# Is there a function that can modify specific data that contains dashes in excel

Tags: excel

I have data stored in an excel column, it is all 9 digit numbers where the last two digits are separated with a dash like in the following image:

[image: Example of 9 digit numbers]

Is there a function that allows me to delete the dash and the two digits after it?

Note: I have more than 1000 lines.

Comment: In place or would a helper column work?

Comment: i didn't get your idea!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use either

1) Find and Replace (search your workbook for `-*` and leave the replace field blank). This will remove a dash and everything after it within your workbook. Note: * is a wildcard character and means it will find everything after a dash in a cell.

2) use the formula `=LEFT(A1, LEN(A1)-3)` to remove the last 3 characters (i.e. the dash and two numbers) from the left side of the cell A1. In my example the formula is for modifying the value in cell A1, you can just drag it down the whole column to do every cell in column A.

It would turn this: `1234567-89`
Into this: `1234567`

I would recommend option 2.

**EDIT - Showing the working formula in Excel.**

[image]

Comment: it didn't work, there is an error

Comment: What is the error...?

Comment: i replaced the cellule A1 , with the cellule i have , it says that there is an error

Comment: It works, see screenshot I just added above. Cell A1 contains data like yours, B1 contains the formula I stated and refers to cell A1.

Comment: i can't see the screenshot or any image , i have technical problem, thanks anyway, i'll try

Comment: Try refreshing this page ;)

Comment: it worked in french

Comment: Great :) you must have a French version of Excel installed? Interesting. Glad it works.  Please mark my post as an answer to accept it, or vote it up... or both if you're feeling generous :) Merry Christmas!

Answer (score 0):

Provided that **all** data in that column follows the same pattern - i.e. a single dash in the entire data - then the following function will solve your problem:

```
=LEFT(A1,FIND("-",A1)-1)
```

It does *not* check for number formatting or anything fancy as the example indicates that not being necessary.

EDIT: This function obviously expects the data to be trimmed start in cell A1 and below. Copy the formula to cell B1, and then copy it to all further cells in column B as required.